# React Draggable component is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a draggable component in my project, but it throws an error whenever I start the dev server -

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at draggable.js:9.
```

Here is my code for draggable.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Draggable } from "react-draggable";
console.log(Draggable); //undefined
export class Board extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Draggable position={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} handle=".handle">
          <div>
            <div className="handle">Drag me</div>
            <div>I will move with the handle</div>
          </div>
        </Draggable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using the console.log statement I have found that the problem is the Draggable component on line 9 is undefined. But after reading the documentation for react-draggable I can't figure out why that is.

I ran npm install react-draggable and checked package.json. The project has react-draggable version 4.4.5 installed

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the import statement

```
import { Draggable } from "react-draggable";
```

to

```
import Draggable from "react-draggable";
```

Note that DraggableCore import statement goes in curly brackets, that was the cause of my confusion